Inductive Definition vs Inductive Proof vs Recursive Definition
I read some answers here that tried to explain the difference between "Inductive Definition" vs "Recursive Definition". But I couldn't really understand the difference between the two. In fact, I am having trouble understanding the difference between the three terms "Inductive Definition", "Recursive Definition", "Inductive Proof".
How are they different? I am not well versed in logic or computer science and this term "Inductive Definition" only came up in my Analysis course with a side note that says "Inductive Definition is not a consequence of Peano's Axioms". Can someone please explain the difference between "Inductive Definition", "Recursive Definition", "Inductive Proof" from the viewpoint of a first year math student?

Everything below is my best attempt from a first year math student viewpoint. I don't think it is the best answer and thus I am making it Community wiki.
An inductive proof is one which uses the principle of mathematical induction to prove a statement. This principle states that if a statement is true for the number $0$, and whenever this statement is true for some natural number $n$, it is also true for $n + 1$, the statement is true for all natural numbers.
An inductive definition(as far as I believe) is just another name for a recursive definition. A recursive(or inductive) definition is when we define something in terms of the thing before it. Consider the following example.
Definition: The factorial of $0$(denoted $0!$) is defined to be $1$. The factorial of any other natural number $n$ is defined to be $n! = n*(n-1)!$.
This definition is recursive(although in my experience mathematicians tend to use the word inductive more) because the factorial of every other number other than $0$ is defined in terms of the factorial of the previous number. For example, the factorial of $1$ is $$1! = 1 * 0! = 1 * 1 = 1$$. The factorial of $2$ is $$2! = 2 * 1! = 2 * 1 * 0! = 2 * 1 * 1 = 2$$ The factorial of $3$ is $$3! = 3 * 2! = 3 * 2 * 1! = 3 * 2 * 1 * 0! = 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 6$$
I am being very pedantic and writing everything out, but I am doing so to demonstrate the recursive(or inductive) nature of the definition. The factorial of every other number other than $0$ is defined in terms of the factorial of the number before it.
